# Lines() command only creates one dot

Tags: r

I'm new to R, therefore, there may be obvious errors in the code. I want this command to plot the S-curve matching my statistics (glm regression). The problem is that the lines command only plots one single dot (watch picture). Where am I doing wrong?

[image]

```r
fit = glm(Konkurser_okat ~ Befolkning, data=data, family=binomial)
newdat <- data.frame(Befolkning=seq(0,291,len=length(Befolkning)))
newdat$Konkurser_okat = predict(fit, newdata=newdat,type="response")
plot(Konkurser_okat~Befolkning,data=data,xlim=c(0,170000),col="red4")
lines(Konkurser_okat ~ Befolkning, newdat, col="green4", lwd=2)
```

Comment: What is the value of `length(Befolkning)`? Anyway, I strongly suggest you use the `curve` function, i.e., after plotting the data: `curve(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(Befolkning = x), type = "response"), add = TRUE, col= "green4", lwd = 2)`. Don't forget to fix the syntax error and add the closing quotation marks after `"red4`.

Comment: Thanks alot! You solved it! I would like them to be S-shaped but they never are, often they are straight positive or like a log-curve. Do you know why this occur?